# PHP AND javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing problem that driving me crazy, I wrote a PHP script that contains a javascript alert .the insertion of the item perform perfectly, but the alert message doesn't appear :(

here is my code

```
 <?php
  if ($city=="jeddah" && $catid=="2")
   {
    $conTL1->autocommit(false); 

    $error =array();

     $q3= $conTL2->query("INSERT INTO productj(product_id,product_name,product_price,product_image,admin_id,
     product_descriptioon,cat_id,quantity,location_id) Values('$pid','$pname','$pprice','$img','$adminid','$pdescription',
     '$catid','$pquantity','$loc')"); 
     $q4= $conTL1->query("INSERT INTO product(product_id,product_name,product_price,product_image,admin_id,
    product_description,cat_id,quantity,location_id) Values('$pid','$pname','$pprice','$img','$adminid','$pdescription',
    '$catid','$pquantity','$loc')"); 

  if($q3==false || $q4==false)
   {
     array_push($error,'Error in adding the product to jeddah databases');                                                      
                    }

                    if(!empty($error))
                    {
                        foreach ($error as $key => $value)
                                {
                                    echo '<script> alert($value);</script>';
                                }
                        $conTL2->rollback();
                        $conTL1->rollback();
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        $conTL2->commit();
                        $conTL1->commit();
                    echo '<script> alert("The item has been added successfully to jeddah database!");</script>';
                    }


            }//end if jeddah
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this line to display alert instead:

`echo "<script> alert('$value');</script>";`

If you need to put variable into your alert, double quotes `"` have to be used outside and single ones `'` inside.

**UPDATE**

or, like @symcbean has mentioned, if you want it to be completely perfect you can do something like:

```
echo "<script> alert('" . addslashes($value) . "');</script>";
```

Comment: I think Naija refers to the else part of the alert...done

Comment: @WilliamMadede you are right actually, but the first alert was still wrong. There is no more javascript problems except that line. But thanks

Comment: ofcourse, im not taking anything away from you...thats actually a good point...done

Comment: erm, should be print "<script> alert('" . addslashes($value) . "');</script>";

Comment: Thank you so much pavlovich <3 I am going to try it